# How to get the alias of a Spark Column as String?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

If I declare a Column in a `val`, like this:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val col: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = count("*").as("col_name")
```

`col` is of type `org.apache.spark.sql.Column`. Is there a way to access its name (`"col_name"`)?
Something like:

```
col.getName() // returns "col_name"
```

In this case, `col.toString` returns `"count(1) AS col_name"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below code.

```
scala> val cl = count("*").as("col_name")
cl: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = count(1) AS `col_name`
```

```
scala> cl.expr.argString
res14: String = col_name
```

```
scala> cl.expr.productElement(1).asInstanceOf[String]
res24: String = col_name
```

```
scala> val cl = count("*").cast("string").as("column_name")
cl: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = CAST(count(1) AS STRING) AS `column_name`

scala> cl.expr.argString
res113: String = column_name
```

From the above code if you alter `.as` & `.cast` It will give you wrong result.

You can also use `json4s` to extract `name` from `expr.toJSON`

```
scala> import org.json4s._
import org.json4s._

scala> import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._
import org.json4s.jackson.JsonMethods._

scala> implicit val formats = DefaultFormats
formats: org.json4s.DefaultFormats.type = org.json4s.DefaultFormats$@16cccda5

scala> val cl = count("*").as("column_name").cast("string") // Used cast last.
cl: org.apache.spark.sql.Column = CAST(count(1) AS `column_name` AS STRING)

scala> (parse(cl.expr.toJSON) \\ "name").extract[String]
res104: String = column_name
```

Comment: I did not understand why it is the wrong result on example 4. It seems the correct result

Comment: if you change this - ```val cl = count("*").cast("string").as("column_name")``` to ```val cl = count("*").as("column_name").cast("string")``` you will get result as ```string``` which is wrong as per your expected output.

Comment: Ahhh ok, if you alter the _order_ of `cast` & `as`, I see. thanks!

Comment: I guess the bottomline here is: there is no built-in simple and robust method to get the column name. The more robust way is parsing the toJSON

Answer (score 0):

One another easy way is, column names will always be covered by `` these characters. You can use either regex or split the string and get `index 1` element.

with `split`,

```
col.toString.split("`")(1)
```

with regex,

```
val pattern = "`(.*)`".r
pattern.findFirstMatchIn(col.toString).get.group(1)
```

Advantage doing like this is even you include something like `.cast("string")` to you column it will still work.